# How to get output of the JS file using VS Code

Tags: javascript, node.js, web-deployment

When I run the code, nothing shows in "Output" tab. I installed nodejs as well as Code runner extension. How to fix this issue?
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/GyraZ.png)

I want to get the output of my code.

Answer (score 0):

1. Install Node.js from https://nodejs.org.
2. open VS Code.
3. from the **file** tab at the top, choose open **folder**.
4. navigate to your working directory where your project is open.
5. from the **terminal** tab at the top, choose **new terminal**.
6. in the terminal, write the following command:

```bash
node sample_1.js
```

*replace the sample_1.js with your file name*

---

This is the *top menu*

[image: the top menu]

and this is the terminal:

[image]

--

and you don't need a *code runner extension*, every time you want to run your JavaScript code, write the command

```
node YOUR_FILE_NAME.js
```

Otherwise, if you want something to automatically detect the changes you make to your file and automatically run the code when you save the file, you'll need a package like `nodemon`.

to install nodemon, in the same working directory, open up the terminal and write the following commands:

```
npm init -y
```

and then:

```
npx nodemon sample_1.js
```

*replace the sample_1.js with your file name*

Nodemon will keep running in the background and every change you make to any of your files in your working directory will make nodemon reload, and you'll see the changes in the terminal immediately.

Answer (score 0):

I fixed that issue. I installed JavaScript Debugger(Nightly). After that now OUTPUT tab shows output of the js file.
https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=ms-vscode.js-debug-nightly

Comment: That's not the solution to your problem, that's a debugger, not a code runner.